# struct in a struct in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, struct

I need help to understand well the use of `struct`

I have this snippet of code:

```
struct PCD
{
    PointCloud::Ptr cloud;
    std::string f_name;
    PCD() : cloud (new PointCloud) {};
};
```

But I don't understand how is possible this row:

```
PCD() : cloud (new PointCloud) {};
```

or better, what does it do? A `struct` in the `struct`?

Where could I find a good explanation of it?

Comment: [Member-initializer list.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list‎)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cloud` is a pointer to a `PointCloud` object. It's a member of the `PCD` struct. When this struct is initialized using the *initializer list*, that pointer is allocated a new `PointCloud` object.

This is likely found in the `PointCloud` struct/class:

```
typedef PointCloud* Ptr;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
PCD() : cloud (new PointCloud) {};
```

is a PCD constructor that initializes the cloud variable with a new PointCloud instance.

```
struct PCD
{
    PointCloud::Ptr cloud;
    std::string f_name;
    PCD() : cloud (new PointCloud) {};
};
```

can be rewritten and visualized as:

```
struct PCD
{
public:
    PointCloud::Ptr cloud;
    std::string f_name;
    PCD();
};

PCD::PCD() : cloud (new PointCloud) {};
```

Answer (score 2):

Struct are a kind of class where everything is public.
Here you are looking a default constructor of struct PCD and the initialization of one of its data member.
We don't know if PointCloud is a struct or a class but it seem that PCD contains a pointer on a instance of that type. so the default constructor create a new instance.

Answer (score 2):

```
PCD() : cloud (new PointCloud) {};
```

This is the default constructor for the structure `PCD`.

The `:` syntax means that a [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) is being used to initialize one or more structure data members.  In this case, the pointer `cloud` is assigned a new, dynamically allocated `PointCloud` object.

Member initializer lists are used to initialize non-static data members *before* the body of the constructor is executed. It is also the only way to initalize reference-type members.

More information about constructors and member initialization lists [here](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/).